# string array literal ? How do I code it simply?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Though that may be a silly question, I can't figure out how to declare an array literal grouping some string literals.

For example, let's assume I want the java array `["January", "February", "March"]`.
How can I translate this into the latest kotlin version `(today, 12.0.0)`?

What have I tried?

```
stringArray("January", "February", "March")
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use arrayOf(), as in

```
val literals = arrayOf("January", "February", "March")
```

Comment: Just a note, really you could do this: **'val literals = arrayOf<String>("January", "February", "March")'** but the argument type **<String>** is already explicit by the content of the array, so it's OK that way and can be omitted.

Comment: Or use `["January", "February", "March"]`

Comment: @yooouuri that is only allowed on annotations and was only just introduced in Kotlin 1.2: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#array-literals-in-annotations

Answer (score 6):

[`arrayOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of.html) (which translates to a [Java `Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)) is one option. This gives you a mutable, fixed-sized container of the elements supplied:

```
val arr = arrayOf("January", "February", "March")
```

that is, there's no way to extend this collection to include more elements but you can mutate its contents.

If, instead of fixed-size, you desire a variable sized collection you can go with [`arrayListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html) or [`mutableListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html) (`mutableListOf` [currently returns an `ArrayList`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L96) but this might at some point change):

```
val arr = arrayListOf("January", "February", "March")    
arr.add("April")
```

Of course, there's also a third option, an immutable fixed-sized collection, `List`. This doesn't support mutation of its contents and can't be extended. To create one, you can use [`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html):

```
val arr = listOf("January", "February", "March")
```